# How to create a dynamic table from java script?

Tags: asp.net

How to create a dynamic table from java script?I am fetching a record from database and storing into variable and adding that value to table cell.
Here I put some text not actual value.

In cs file's button click event I doing like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
sb.Append("<table><tbody><tr><td>Information</td></tr></tbody></table>");
sb.Append(@"</script>");

if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup"))

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup", sb.ToString());
```

But I am unable to see Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add document.Write in your script

```
so replace with

sb.Append("document.write('<table><tbody><tr><td>Information</td></tr></tbody></table>');");
```

Comment: If there is condition like ,if(str1 == 'gfgfg'){<tr><td>gfgf</td></tr>}?Does i need to do in C# or javascript?

Comment: I don't inderstood Jui, do you want add condition ?

Comment: string s1  = "Computer";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
sb.Append("<table><tbody><tr><td>Information</td></tr>")
if(s1 == "Computer" )
sb.Append("<tr><td>s1</td></tr>");

</tbody></table>");
sb.Append(@"</script>");

if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup"))

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup", sb.ToString()); Then how to write document.write  for all.

Comment: Jui try with :
        string s1 = "Computer"; 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>"); 
        sb.Append("<table><tbody><tr><td>Information</td></tr>");
 
        if(s1 == "Computer" ) sb.Append("<tr><td>s1</td></tr>"); 

        sb.Append("</tbody></table>"); 
        sb.Append(@"</script>");